# Changing the default position of Angular material dropdown and text

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Im trying to change the position of Material dropdown panel to the bottom of the dropdown button. And trying to vertically center the name and arrow to the dropdown region.
Please go through the image which I'm trying to achieve.

```
<div class="dropDown">
   <mat-select disableOptionCentering placeholder="Select any value">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let item of list" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</div>


.dropDown{
 width:200px;
 height:40px;
 background-color: white;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: does this [github discussion](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/14105) and [stackblitz exmple](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khatke-8xhpbc?file=index.html) work?

Comment: you can add it to your CSS (which is preferred), or you can just add `style="margin: 25px 0px"` to your html for a quick fix. either should work.

Comment: By using ng-deep before the panel class, it's working. Thank you. Any idea about the second part of the question? which is about vertical centering the text of drop-down

Comment: `position: relative; translate:  transform: translateY(50%);` try this css

Comment: It didn't work. Including any link would be helpful as before

Comment: I am trying [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp) currently, but I can't get it to work in the stackblitz I'm playing with. I also was looking at `padding-top: calc(100% - 10px);` but I don't know where to add it in your html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the drop down displaying below the selection box, add reference the following css to the `panelClass`:

```
.myPanelClass{
    margin: 25px 0px;
}
```

Then for the centering of your text, reference the following css in the `class`:

```
.mySelectClass {
  padding-top: 12px;
}
```

and then add them into the html as so

```
<div class="dropDown">
   <mat-select disableOptionCentering 
               placeholder="Select any value"
               panelClass="myPanelClass"
               class="mySelectClass">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let item of list" [value]="item">{{item}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</div>
```

here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khatke-z4uflc?file=styles.css)

Answer (score -1):

This will help:

```
disableOptionCentering="true"
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).