# Is there a way we can change the dropdown from select tag to open to the right side?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I wanted to open the drop-down from the select tag to open to the right side(drop-right) is there a way I can do that ?

```html
<label for="ExpLabel">Select Message Expiry:</label>

<select name="ExpSelect" id="Expiry">
  <option value="ExpiryDate">1 Day</option>
  <option value="ExpiryDate">2 Days</option>
  <option value="ExpiryDate">3 Days</option>
  <option value="ExpiryDate">4 Days</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you make a picture of what you mean?

Comment: Hi, Im not able to attach an example picture . i wanted to move the dropdown which opens below to the right side of the box

Comment: You cannot style a built-in select like that. Find a select like select2

Comment: is there anything we can do with css to bring the dropdown to the right??

Comment: If you can use angular material's `mat-select`, you'd be able to do this with CSS. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458705/13913033)

Comment: you can use .css `direction:rtt`, see [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

Answer (score 0):

You could simulate a select box like this and style it any way you want.

```js
const sel = document.querySelector("#selected");
/* Create an array with the options */
const opt = [...document.querySelectorAll(".option")];
const inp = document.querySelector("#sel");

sel.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const opts = document.querySelector("#options");
  if (opts.classList.contains("open")) {
    /* If the <ul> is visible, hide it */
    opts.classList.remove("open");
  } else {
    /* If the <ul> is hidden, show it */
    opts.classList.add("open");
  }
});

opt.forEach((e, i, o) => {
  /* Add an event listener for each option */
  o[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    /* Store the value of the option in a variable */
    const chosen = e.querySelector("span").innerHTML;
    const opts = document.querySelector("#options");
    /* Assign the value of the option to the select box */
    sel.innerHTML = chosen;
    /* Assign the value of the option to the hidden input field */
    inp.value = chosen;
    /* And close the <ul> */
    opts.classList.remove("open");
  });
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

#selected {
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  padding-left: .5em;
  min-width: 170px;
  position: relative;
}

#selected:after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0d7";
  margin-left: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
}

#options {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#options.open {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="sel">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="selected">Select Message Expiry</div>
    <ul id="options">
      <li class="option"><span>1 Day</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>2 Days</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>3 Days</span></li>
      <li class="option"><span>4 Days</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```